# execute a callback(via function ptr) from dll

Tags: go, dll, cgo

I got a callback from a dll,
the function ptr type defined:

```
typedef int32_t (WINAPI *fn) ();
```

if I use cgo, we can do like this:

```golang
/*
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int32_t (WINAPI *fn) ();

int32_t call_callback(fn f){
   f();
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {

    var callBackPtr uintptr // from dll function

    C.call_callback((C.fn)(unsafe.Pointer(callBackPtr)))

}
```

BUT! I don't want to use cgo. How can I achieve in pure go?

Comment: Don't think it will work. You can call DLL functions from go without cgo with simple datatype args by serializing them with `syscall` [article here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs); however, I don't think you can (or should) be able to use syscall pass a go func and as c func without cgo. The Go memory manager probably wouldn't tolerate this without cgo as well

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18296) opened in 2013 indicates "one of the points of Cgo is to make this work in the first place". The latest comments ([this one](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18296#issuecomment-468477837) and [this one](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18296#issuecomment-1221724761)) point to two repositories : a [POC](https://github.com/notti/nocgo) by author of first comment, and a [subproject of ebitengine](https://github.com/ebitengine/purego)

Comment: thk, i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

just

```golang
   syscall.SyscallN(callBackPtr, [callBack's arg])
```

....